# what does the presence of & mean in const_cast template parameter

Tags: c++, casting, const-cast

I was going over the following example

```
const int a = 12;
int b;
b = const_cast<int&>(a);
```

and I wanted to know what `&` in the template parameter type signifies above and why it wont work without the `&` ?

**Update:**

Let me rephrase my question . I understand its a reference but what variable is it referring to ? For instance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz6at95h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it states that incase of pointers it references the original (uncast) pointer. I want to know what it references incase of non pointer types and how can `b` b a reference when it wasnt declared as a reference ?

Comment: If you don't recognize a reference, you should probably take a step back and read a good beginner C++ good/tutorial.

Comment: Its significance is... wait for it... **a reference!**

Comment: Let me rephrase my question . I know its a reference but what variable is it referring to ? For instance in  msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz6at95h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx it states that incase of pointers it references the original (uncast) pointer. I want to know what it references incase of non pointer types

Comment: It doesn't refer to any variable. It solely indicates the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const_cast` is not a template, but rather a type cast. What appears to be a template argument is the destination type for the cast, and in this case it means that you want to obtain a non-const reference to `int` that refers to the same objects as `a`.

Comment: So the destination type is a reference then am I correct ? If so what is it a reference of ? is a temporary object created in memory ? I tried this with pointers and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz6at95h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx states that it references the  original (uncast) pointer. I want to know what happens incase of non pointers

Comment: @MistyD: It references the object that is the argument to the cast.

Comment: I am still confused on how it can reference something when it is declared as `int b` and not as `int &b`

Comment: @MistyD: The cast generates a non-const reference, that reference is used to copy the value to `b`. `b` is not a reference to `a`, but an `int` variable that holds a copy of `a`. The cast is unnecessary in that code (and even confusing)

Comment: Thanks that explains it. I just wanted to be sure that there was copying involved

Answer (score 1):

`a` is `const int&` when you do the `const_cast` as you wrote it.

You can only modify cv-qualifiers of pointer and reference types with `const_cast`, not of values. This is because specifying constness for rvalues only makes sense if this is of reference or pointer type and can thus be modified.

So if you just want the (non-const) value of the variable `a`, simply write

```
b = a;
```

as the const-ness is ignored anyway. `b` is then copy-constructed from `a`.

Comment: *constness is ignored for values*? You might want to further explain what you mean, as it stands that is incorrect

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I corrected it to "rvalues", is this now correct? What I mean is that when I use a const value in an expression (rvalue?), its constness doesn't matter. Only when I try to assign to it (lvalue?). But maybe I don't know the correct terminology for this.

Comment: in the first line you wrote `a is const int&` could you exlain what that means ? as my code has `const int`

Comment: I mean this: http://ideone.com/ORASWu What I wanted to say: As soon as the variable of const primitive type is part of an expression, it's `int`, neither `const int&`, nor `const int`, nor `int&`. It doesn't make sense to modify the *result* of an expression, thus there's no sense to say an expression is const. But this can be of course different if we consider user-defined types.

Comment: I tried to reformulate what I wanted to say, please see my edit. I find it a bit difficult to express this ;)

Comment: @leemes: You are restricting the scope to fundamental types, but giving a blank statement without qualification. Const-ness *matters* even for *rvalues*, just not for *rvalues* of fundamental types. Consider `struct T { void mutate(); }; const T f(); f().mutate();`. The expression `f()` is an *rvalue* expression of type `const T`, `const` matters and you are not allowed to call `mutate()` on it. Change the return type to `T f();` and the above code will compile.

Comment: ... I understand where you want to get to, but the wording is wrong. As I understand your intention is to say that it does not make sense to cast away const-ness of a *copy*, but you want to cast away the `const` out of a pointer or reference that references the original object. Once you copy you can make the copy non-const and there is no need for the `const_cast`.

Comment: Well, but `a+1` is not a copy afaik. It's a fresh value, a temporary, an rvalue, ... I don't know how to better describe it to distinguish it from `a` itself. Unless `operator+` does strange stuff, `a+1` does *not* refer to an existing value *living* somewhere outside of the temporary expression (in a variable e.g.; for example like you called it "the original object") and thus it doesn't make sense to modify it. These words are now of course again vague.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a is const, b is not const

so const_cast basically says b is stored at a but removes the const.